# HTML parsing in Android

Tags: android, parsing, rss, html-parsing, rss-reader

I am trying to learn how to parse HTML, but as I don't have a lot of experience in either Java or Android, it's a little complicated. I have read the IBM XML parsing tutorial and have learned to parse an RSS feed. My problem is: I would like to get data from an HTML site. I have read some information on HTML cleaner, JSON, etc., but I can't find a good tutorial to help me. Do you have any tutorials that might be helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following HTML parsers. There are more out there. Maybe one will work for you:

- HTMLCleaner:
  http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/
- TagSoup:
  http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/
- Jericho:
  http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that i m looking for is a tutorial on this parsers

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are two easy ways to parse HTML:

- Convert the HML to XML (XHTML) using a library (e.g. HTMLTidy) and then use an XML parser
- Use an existing HTML parser (e.g. a standard Web browser like WebKit, ForeFox, and/or IE) and then read the "DOM" which is a more-or-less-API-friendly representation of the parsed HTML

Alternatively, if you want to write your own parser (which I doubt you should, for homework: it would be long and complicated to implement it properly/completely), see the [specs for parsing HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing).

Comment: I made this CW because it doesn't exactly answer to question and so someone might want to edit/correct it: e.g. this answer isn't android-specific and isn't a tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your answer!so there is a way to convert the html to xml and then get the data as rss?

Comment: @kostas I don't know, and I think you'd better ask that as a separate/new question.