# How to parse jsp file from android application

Tags: android, parsing, jsp, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831513/html-parsing-in-android)

I'm new to program, hope someone can teach me! 
I want to develop an Android Apps that can view the timetable from my university's server.

here's the server side:
http://webapps.apiit.edu.my/schedule/intakeview_intake.jsp?Intake1=UC1F1205IT&Submit=Submit&Week=

UC1F1205IT is my intake code,different intake code will get different timetable.

Now how should i parse the return file? And how can i put different information to different block?
Thanks for teaching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a similiar questions
[Android HTML Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867746/android-html-parser-example).
[What's a suitable html parser for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167611/whats-a-suitable-html-parser-for-android)

you can use java html parser like jsoup . http://jsoup.org/

Comment: thx ya, trying to parse it.